# How to monitor another program / process

Tags: process, display

How to monitor another program/process about what it is doing?(on both Windows and Linux)

Say, I was going to run an application to another computer. But, it crashes after I run it. That program didn't had any logging system. So I had absolutely no Idea where/how to look into this issue.

So, Is there any 3rd party software or anything that might help me to monitor another program and check for when exactly for what reason the application was crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on Linux or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645) on Windows. The other option is to attach a debugger.