# Program crash in Win7/X64 related to filenames with % in them

Tags: windows-7

For a while now I've had this reproducible error:

If I try to open any file (so regardless of its extension) that has a `%` in its name, regardless of the method of opening (click on it in Explorer, open it manually in the command prompt etc.), the program which is used to send the request (Explorer and cmd.exe, in the previous examples) would crash 100%.

Does anyone know the exact mechanism/sequence Windows uses to open a file? I could help out with debug information that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long road from the point where you double-click on an icon on screen to the point where an application is started.

There is a **lot** go wrong.

1. You click on a file.
2. Windows determines the file **type**.
3. Can this file be executed on its own, or does it require another application to open it?
   Let's check what the registry says about the file extension.
4. Registry says it's a `txtfile`.
5. Registry says, to `open` a `txtfile` we should use a program called `C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE`
6. Now we can finally create our process:
   [image: Process Create Event captures in Process Monitor]

There is so much stuff involved, there is no way of telling what exactly is the problem. You need to perform further investigations yourself.

Please have a look at:

- [How do I troubleshoot when I have no clue where to start?](https://superuser.com/questions/260043/how-do-i-troubleshoot-when-i-have-no-clue-where-to-start)
- [How to monitor another program / process](https://superuser.com/questions/268843/how-to-monitor-another-program-process)

Comment: But it also crashes if I, say, try `notepad.exe blub%.txt`, which skips a lot of your described steps, shouldn't that narrow it down?

Comment: @BuoteXu: Yes, it narrows it down from 10 trillion possible reasons to 5 trillion possible reasons. To be more serious, yes, it does, but not by enough to make me able to know what's going on without having more detailed data.

Comment: Solved it, the crash was caused by Spybot's `SDHook32.dll`, which somehow couldn't deal with the filename.

Comment: @BuoteXu: Please keep in mind that it is perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept that as the correct solution, if you're able to solve your problem yourself. This could help future users.